# Add one day to 'Event End Date' with JavaScript (WordPress, Timber/Twig)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, twig, timber

I need to add one day to 'end_date', which is set in the Post itself (WordPress)

Here's the entire code snippet:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

      var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        events: [
        {% for post in events %}
        {
          title  : '{{ post.title }} | {{ post.location }}',
          start  : '{{ post.start_date|date('Y-m-d') }}',
          end    : '{{ post.end_date|date('Y-m-d') }}',
          color  : '{{ post.type }}'
        },
        {% endfor %}
        ],
        plugins: [ 'dayGrid' ]
      });

      calendar.render();
    });
```

Anyone know how this can best be done? Preferably within this code snippet.

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at [date_modify](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/date_modify.html)

Comment: Doesn't work because of epoch.

Comment: What do you mean? Works just fine - [demo](https://twigfiddle.com/qy5tae)

Comment: Because WordPress is outputting the date like '20200311" (yyyymmdd)

If i use date_modify it comes out as August 22, 1970

Comment: If that's the case then even the `date` filter will not work properly as `20200311` is not a valid datetime notation

Answer (score 0):

You would first have convert your time into to a datetime object. For that, I would use a function:

**functions.php**

```php
function convert_date_to_format( $date_string, $format = 'Y-m-d' ) {
    $date = DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat(
        'Ymd',
        $date_string
    );

    return $date->format( $format );
}
```

Because you already know the date format of your date string (`Ymd`), you can use `DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat()`.

A datetime object in PHP has a `format()` method to output your date in the format you define.

Here’s you could use the function in your case:

```
{% for post in events %}
    {
      title : '{{ post.title }} | {{ post.location }}',
      start : '{{ fn('convert_date_to_format', post.start_date, 'Y-m-d') }}',
      end   : '{{ fn('convert_date_to_format', post.end_date, 'Y-m-d') }}',
      color : '{{ post.type }}'
    },
{% endfor %}
```

Now, this is actually a perfect use case for [extending your post](https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/extending-timber/) and moving your logic from Twig to PHP. If you have access to defining your `post` variable, you could create a specific class for your event posts by extending `Timber\Post`.

```php
<?php

class EventPost extends Timber\Post {
    /**
     * Converts a date from Ymd format to another format.
     *
     * @param string $date_string The date string in Ymd format.
     * @param string $format      The desired output format.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function convert_date_to_format( $date_string, $format ) {
        $date = DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat(
            'Ymd',
            $date_string
        );

        return $date->format( $format );
    }

    /**
     * Gets formatted start date.
     *
     * @param string $format Optional. The preferred format. Default `Y-m-d`.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function start_date( $format = 'Y-m-d' ) {
        $date = $this->meta( 'start_date' );

        return $this->convert_date_to_format( $date, $format );
    }

    /**
     * Gets formatted end date.
     *
     * @param string $format Optional. The preferred format. Default `Y-m-d`.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function end_date( $format = 'Y-m-d' ) {
        $date = $this->meta( 'end_date' );

        return $this->convert_date_to_format( $date, $format );
    }
}
```

You could prepare `post` like this.

```php
$context['post'] = new EventPost();
```

Your Twig template would then look like this:

```
{% for post in events %}
    {
      title : '{{ post.title }} | {{ post.location }}',
      start : '{{ post.start_date('Y-m-d') }}',
      end   : '{{ post.end_date('Y-m-d') }}',
      color : '{{ post.type }}'
    },
{% endfor %}
```